# When exactly is the transaction finished with prebid.js?

Tags: google-dfp, prebid.js, prebid, header-bidding

I wonder what is the exact event that triggers the payment?

Considering the following example:

1. prebid.js realizes the auction on any specific ad slot
2. a partner responds with a valid creative and wins the impression
3. the creative is rendered in the ad slot

If something happen between steps 2 and 3 that prevents the creative to be rendered, will the partner simply lose his offer? (eg. will he have to pay the publisher even if nothing has been actually inserted in the page).

I've seen several webpages where the steps 3, "rendering", seems to be bound with the ad slot visibility.
The prebid.js "rendered" event is only triggered when scrolling to the adslot position.
(I've seen this especially with videos advertising, but not sure if this precision is accurate)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Correct, step 3 is where the transaction takes place. This of course depends on the SSP. For example some only count the transaction when:

- the ad url is called
- after the creative renders
- after the creative renders and is visible

Disclaimer: I work at Xandr